# Inserting numbers from a list in a repeating sentence

Tags: windows, excel, text, random, ms-word

I have a list of all 5 digit combinations possible and I also have a sentence in which I would like to add each number. Here's an example:

- List items:

11111, 22222, 33333.. etc

- Sentence:

Hello userXXXXX, how are you?

- Desired result:

  1. Hello user11111, how are you?
  2. Hello user22222, how are you?
  3. Hello user33333, how are you?

The list of numbers is huge and the sentence keeps changing. I need a way to do this automatically.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: If I were to answer the question you ask it would be: probably. You don't provide enough information. Which programming language / programming environment will you use? Where is the sentence to repeat coming from? Exactly which tags are relevant to this question - certainly not all of them... What effort have you made to solve this, on your own and what tripped you up?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not looking to do this in any programming language. All tags are somewhat relevant. I asked Mr. Google and found out that there may a way to do this in Excel using custom lists, but I didn't have any luck. I'm looking to getting the desired result through a piece of software, in a text document (hence the tags Excel, text, MS Word.) If I knew exactly what program I could use to get this done, I wouldn't have asked, but look for tutorials. :)

Answer (score 0):

Place the list in column **A**.  Place this template sentence in cell **B1**:

```
Hello user XXXXX, how are you?
```

In **C1** enter:

```
=LEFT($B$1,FIND("XXXXX",$B$1)-1) & INDEX(A:A,ROWS($1:1)) & MID($B$1,FIND("XXXXX",$B$1)+5,9999)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Right now I'm having trouble adding such a huge list into excel. The Custom List seems to have some sort of maximum character set which doesn't seem to be changeable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (Excel), copied across and down to suit:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B$1,"XXXXX",$A2)
```

[image]